# Multiple GCC version problem

Tags: dpkg, dependencies, gcc

I'm having a lot of problems with GCC. First, I tried to install an app (ginga) and I got a GCC depends issue. The depend is about have an gcc version, but the application needs other one. I installed the version asked, but the conflicts still. So, I got a lot of issues with GCC and now I can't install anything because of depends. When I try to install something a have this output:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 build-essential : Depends: gcc (>= 4:4.4.3) but it is not going to be installed
                   Depends: g++ (>= 4:4.4.3) but it is not going to be installed
                   Depends: dpkg-dev (>= 1.13.5) but it is not going to be installed
 cpp-4.8 : Depends: gcc-4.8-base (= 4.8.4-1) but 4.8.5-1 is to be installed
 dkms : Depends: gcc but it is not going to be installed
 gcc-4.8 : Depends: gcc-4.8-base (= 4.8.4-1) but 4.8.5-1 is to be installed
           Depends: binutils (>= 2.24.90.20141219) but 2.24-5ubuntu13 is to be installed
           Depends: libgcc-4.8-dev (>= 4.8.4-1) but it is not going to be installed
 gcc-multilib : Depends: gcc (>= 4:4.8.2-1ubuntu6) but it is not going to be installed
                Depends: gcc-4.8-multilib (>= 4.8.2-5~) but it is not going to be installed
 libasan0 : Depends: gcc-4.8-base (= 4.8.4-1) but 4.8.5-1 is to be installed
 libatomic1 : Depends: gcc-4.8-base (= 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04) but 4.8.5-1 is to be installed
 libc6:i386 : Depends: libgcc1:i386 but it is not going to be installed
 libgcc1 : Depends: gcc-4.7-base (= 4.7.2-5) but it is not going to be installed
 libgfortran3 : Depends: gcc-4.8-base (= 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04) but 4.8.5-1 is to be installed
 libgl1-mesa-dri-lts-utopic:i386 : Depends: libgcc1:i386 (>= 1:4.7) but it is not going to be installed
 libglu1-mesa:i386 : Depends: libgcc1:i386 (>= 1:4.1.1) but it is not going to be installed
 libgomp1 : Depends: gcc-4.8-base (= 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04) but 4.8.5-1 is to be installed
 libitm1 : Depends: gcc-4.8-base (= 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04) but 4.8.5-1 is to be installed
 libjack-jackd2-0:i386 : Depends: libgcc1:i386 (>= 1:4.1.1) but it is not going to be installed
 libllvm3.5:i386 : Depends: libgcc1:i386 (>= 1:4.1.1) but it is not going to be installed
 libmysqlclient18:i386 : Depends: libgcc1:i386 (>= 1:4.1.1) but it is not going to be installed
 libqt4-declarative:i386 : Depends: libgcc1:i386 (>= 1:4.1.1) but it is not going to be installed
 libqt4-network:i386 : Depends: libgcc1:i386 (>= 1:4.1.1) but it is not going to be installed
 libqt4-opengl:i386 : Depends: libgcc1:i386 (>= 1:4.1.1) but it is not going to be installed
 libqt4-script:i386 : Depends: libgcc1:i386 (>= 1:4.1.1) but it is not going to be installed
 libqt4-scripttools:i386 : Depends: libgcc1:i386 (>= 1:4.1.1) but it is not going to be installed
 libqt4-sql:i386 : Depends: libgcc1:i386 (>= 1:4.1.1) but it is not going to be installed
 libqt4-sql-mysql:i386 : Depends: libgcc1:i386 (>= 1:4.1.1) but it is not going to be installed
 libqt4-xml:i386 : Depends: libgcc1:i386 (>= 1:4.1.1) but it is not going to be installed
 libqt4-xmlpatterns:i386 : Depends: libgcc1:i386 (>= 1:4.1.1) but it is not going to be installed
 libqtcore4:i386 : Depends: libgcc1:i386 (>= 1:4.1.1) but it is not going to be installed
 libqtdbus4:i386 : Depends: libgcc1:i386 (>= 1:4.1.1) but it is not going to be installed
 libqtgui4:i386 : Depends: libgcc1:i386 (>= 1:4.1.1) but it is not going to be installed
 libqtwebkit4:i386 : Depends: libgcc1:i386 (>= 1:4.1.1) but it is not going to be installed
 libquadmath0 : Depends: gcc-4.8-base (= 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04) but 4.8.5-1 is to be installed
 libstdc++-4.8-dev : Depends: gcc-4.8-base (= 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04) but 4.8.5-1 is to be installed
                     Depends: libgcc-4.8-dev (= 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04) but it is not going to be installed
 libstdc++6 : Depends: gcc-4.9-base (= 4.9.1-16ubuntu6) but 4.9.3-4 is to be installed
 libstdc++6:i386 : Depends: gcc-4.9-base:i386 (= 4.9.1-16ubuntu6) but it is not going to be installed
                   Depends: libgcc1:i386 (>= 1:4.1.1) but it is not going to be installed
 libtsan0 : Depends: gcc-4.8-base (= 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04) but 4.8.5-1 is to be installed
 sa-compile : Depends: gcc but it is not going to be installed
 simplescreenrecorder-lib:i386 : Depends: libgcc1:i386 (>= 1:4.1.1) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

---

Could you help me? I really don't know what to do.

---

pl_rock. First, thanks to help me.

I did what you suggest, but it didn't work. The answer for "apt-get -f install" is: E: Unable to correct dependencies

To purge the gcc I had to use "--force-all" and after purge gcc (4.8 and 4.9) a tried the apt-get autoremove, but I got the same output:

`root@gleidson-Inspiron-5423:/home/gleidson# apt-get autoremove 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree

Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 cpp-4.8 : Depends: gcc-4.8-base (= 4.8.4-1) but it is not installed
 dkms : Depends: gcc but it is not installed
 gcc-multilib : Depends: gcc (>= 4:4.8.2-1ubuntu6) but it is not installed
                Depends: gcc-4.8-multilib (>= 4.8.2-5~) but it is not installed
 libasan0 : Depends: gcc-4.8-base (= 4.8.4-1) but it is not installed
 libatomic1 : Depends: gcc-4.8-base (= 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04) but it is not installed
 libc6:i386 : Depends: libgcc1:i386 but it is not installed
 libgcc1 : Depends: gcc-4.7-base (= 4.7.2-5) but it is not installed
 libgfortran3 : Depends: gcc-4.8-base (= 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04) but it is not installed
 libgl1-mesa-dri-lts-utopic:i386 : Depends: libgcc1:i386 (>= 1:4.7) but it is not installed
 libglu1-mesa:i386 : Depends: libgcc1:i386 (>= 1:4.1.1) but it is not installed
 libgomp1 : Depends: gcc-4.8-base (= 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04) but it is not installed
 libitm1 : Depends: gcc-4.8-base (= 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04) but it is not installed
 libjack-jackd2-0:i386 : Depends: libgcc1:i386 (>= 1:4.1.1) but it is not installed
 libllvm3.5:i386 : Depends: libgcc1:i386 (>= 1:4.1.1) but it is not installed
 libmysqlclient18:i386 : Depends: libgcc1:i386 (>= 1:4.1.1) but it is not installed
 libqt4-declarative:i386 : Depends: libgcc1:i386 (>= 1:4.1.1) but it is not installed
 libqt4-network:i386 : Depends: libgcc1:i386 (>= 1:4.1.1) but it is not installed
 libqt4-opengl:i386 : Depends: libgcc1:i386 (>= 1:4.1.1) but it is not installed
 libqt4-script:i386 : Depends: libgcc1:i386 (>= 1:4.1.1) but it is not installed
 libqt4-scripttools:i386 : Depends: libgcc1:i386 (>= 1:4.1.1) but it is not installed
 libqt4-sql:i386 : Depends: libgcc1:i386 (>= 1:4.1.1) but it is not installed
 libqt4-sql-mysql:i386 : Depends: libgcc1:i386 (>= 1:4.1.1) but it is not installed
 libqt4-xml:i386 : Depends: libgcc1:i386 (>= 1:4.1.1) but it is not installed
 libqt4-xmlpatterns:i386 : Depends: libgcc1:i386 (>= 1:4.1.1) but it is not installed
 libqtcore4:i386 : Depends: libgcc1:i386 (>= 1:4.1.1) but it is not installed
 libqtdbus4:i386 : Depends: libgcc1:i386 (>= 1:4.1.1) but it is not installed
 libqtgui4:i386 : Depends: libgcc1:i386 (>= 1:4.1.1) but it is not installed
 libqtwebkit4:i386 : Depends: libgcc1:i386 (>= 1:4.1.1) but it is not installed
 libquadmath0 : Depends: gcc-4.8-base (= 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04) but it is not installed
 libstdc++-4.8-dev : Depends: gcc-4.8-base (= 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04) but it is not installed
                     Depends: libgcc-4.8-dev (= 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04) but it is not installed
 libstdc++6 : Depends: gcc-4.9-base (= 4.9.1-16ubuntu6) but it is not installed
 libstdc++6:i386 : Depends: gcc-4.9-base:i386 (= 4.9.1-16ubuntu6) but it is not installed
                   Depends: libgcc1:i386 (>= 1:4.1.1) but it is not installed
 libtsan0 : Depends: gcc-4.8-base (= 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04) but it is not installed
 sa-compile : Depends: gcc but it is not installed
 simplescreenrecorder-lib:i386 : Depends: libgcc1:i386 (>= 1:4.1.1) but it is not installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try using -f.`

And, if I use the "-f" as suggest I got: E: Unable to correct dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

you are getting this problem because you reinstalled `gcc` but there older dependency still exist that conflicting with new dependency . so run command :

```
apt-get -f install
```

it will resolve dependency then install `gcc` . 
if you still face problem then purge gcc and then run command :

```
 sudo apt-get autoremove
```

it will remove older dependency then reinstall gcc and there dependency